# TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null - testing vue component with async functions

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, frontend, babel-jest

I am testing a component ComponentA.spec.js but I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null`. It works if I get rid of the await keyword in the getData() function in the ComponentA. I am mocking the getData api call in my test but still it doesn't work.

This is the full stack
TypeError: C:[Privacy]\unknown: Cannot read property 'type' of null

```js
at assert (node_modules/@babel/types/lib/asserts/generated/index.js:284:112)
at Object.assertIdentifier (node_modules/@babel/types/lib/asserts/generated/index.js:373:3)
at new CatchEntry (node_modules/regenerator-transform/lib/leap.js:93:5)
at Emitter.Ep.explodeStatement (node_modules/regenerator-transform/lib/emit.js:535:36)
at node_modules/regenerator-transform/lib/emit.js:323:12
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Emitter.Ep.explodeStatement (node_modules/regenerator-transform/lib/emit.js:322:22)
at Emitter.Ep.explode (node_modules/regenerator-transform/lib/emit.js:280:40)
```

This is Component A that i am trying to create tests for

```js
<template>
  <div class="d-flex flex-row">
    <component-b />
    <component-c />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ComponentB from './ComponentB';
import ComponentC from './ComponentC';
import { getData } from 'apis';
export default {
  name: 'component-a',
  components: {
    ComponentB,
    ComponentC,
  },
  async created() {
    await this.getData();
  },
  methods: {
    // This function is the culprit
    async getData() {
      try {
        const response = await getData();
      } catch {
        //
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

This is my ComponentA.spec.js file

```js
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import ComponentA from 'components/ComponentA';
import { createLocalVue, shallowMount, mount } from '@vue/test-utils';

jest.mock('shared/apis', () => {
  const data = require('../fixedData/data.json');

  return {
    getData: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(data),
  };
});

const localVue = createLocalVue();
let vuetify;

function createShallowWrapper(options = {}) {
  return shallowMount(ComponentA, {
    localVue,
    vuetify,
    ...options,
  });
}

beforeEach(() => {
  vuetify = new Vuetify();
});

describe('ComponentA', () => {
  describe('component creation', () => {
    test('testing', () => {
      const wrapper = createShallowWrapper();
      expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share anything more than this as it will be a breach of privacy. I am sure async function here is the culprit as if I comment it out and run the test it works. I am sure I need to mock it but just not sure how. I mocked the api call but that didn't make it work. I am out of ideas now. getData is being used in the created hook of ComponentA.

Comment: The problem in the updated question is you're mocking `'shared/apis'` but you're importing from `'apis'`. Should work if you mock `'apis'`. The module name has to match.

Comment: That didn't work too, same error message. :(

Comment: On general principles, I'd also advise on moving the api call from `created()` to `mounted()`. Not that it doesn't work in `created()` but it might give you the false impression the component creation or its mounting is delayed until the data has been fetched, which is not true. The component gets created and mounted without waiting for the `await` code to finish (and whatever you place after it). And the component still needs to handle the case where data has not yet been loaded (show a loading state or prevent rendering by using a `v-if`).

Comment: Can't help you more without a runnable example. The only other problem I see is you're matching against `wrapper`, not `wrapper.element`, but it's unlikely the the source of the error. Best of luck fixing it.

Comment: Adding (e) to my catch in the getData function in ComponentA fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding exception variable (e) to my catch in the getData function in ComponentA fixed it.